# HTML form to PHP script not sending mail

Tags: php, html, email

I'm using a template to create my website and it came with a contact page and form all set out but it did not have a php contact script so I wrote that up and set it as the action on the html form and it still won't send me anything to my email... which I have set up through gmail ( i changed the domain email exchange DNS to the gmail settings)
in the html contact form i have the following code:

```
<div id="contact_form"><form method="post" name="contact" action="contact-form-handler.php">                        
<label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="required input_field" /><div class="cleaner h10"></div>
<label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate-email required input_field" /><div class="cleaner h10"></div>                       
<label for="subject">Subject:</label> <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input_field" /><div class="cleaner h10"></div>      
<label for="text">Message:</label> <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea><div class="cleaner h10"></div>                      
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" />  
<input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" name="reset" class="submit_btn float_r" />
</form>
```

and the contact-form-handler.php contains this code bellow to process the html form:

```
<?php
$to = 'info@jamesreborne.co.uk';
$to .= 'damgxx@gmail.com';

// Assigning data from the $_POST array to variables
$name = $_post['sender_name'];
$email = $_post['sender_email'];
$subject = $_post['sender_subject'];
$text = $_post['sender_text'];

// Construct email subject
$content = 'www.jamesreborne.co.uk Message from visitor ' . $name;

// Construct email body
$body_message = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $email. "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\r\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: ' . $text;

// Construct email headers
$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";

mail($to, $content, $body_message, $headers);

$mail_sent = mail($to, $content, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_sent == true){ ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php } 

else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message not sent. Please, notify the site administrator info@jamesreborne.co.uk');
    window.location = 'contact.html';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

if anyone can help that would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
```

Also there is no form field for name and email. Add that.

Comment: thanks for your reply... I added the name and email but it wasn't properly formatted when posting the question. I also changed the $subject = $_post['subject']; to $subject = $_POST['subject']; and also with the text and still no success. any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is also an error in the part where you set recipients' emails - they are not separated so the `$to` variable is `info@jamesreborne.co.ukdamgxx@gmail.com`. It should me more like this:

```
<?php
$to = 'info@jamesreborne.co.uk';
$to .= ', damgxx@gmail.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

First your  $to string adds two emails in wrong way,
 it should be:

```
   $to = 'info@jamesreborne.co.uk, ';
   $to .= 'damgxx@gmail.com';
```

Even if you correct that you wont get subject and message value. AFAIK $_POST is case sensetive(please correct if wrong). So you will have to make it $_POST not $_post.

Then the names of the inputs in html form and in php code are not matching. They should be:

```
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $text = $_POST['text'];
```

If a input field in form is subject, then

`$subject = $_POST['subject'];`

NOT

```
$subject = $_POST['sender_subject'];
```

EDIT:

If you are still not getting email, then your server might not have **mail server** installed. 
Install [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) and try.

Comment: Thanks i have corrected the above, it is still not sending the mail, i checked my spam folder but i remain disappointed. I dont know what else to try, any more ideas? thanks.

Comment: is it in your localhost or production server ? If localhost then you will have to install postfix(or other mail server) to get email.

Comment: Even in production server, if mail server is not already installed then you will have to install it. I have checked in my computer it sending email. So I am sure there is some problem with mail server.